# ¿Por qué no funciona con la primera key del diccionario?

Tags: python

```
frutas_precios = {'melones': 4, 'limones': 2}

for keys in frutas_precios:
print(keys)

fruta_quiere = input('Que fruta le interesa (escriba ninguna para salir del modo de compra): ')
if fruta_quiere == (keys):
    precio = frutas_precios[fruta_quiere]
    print(f'Usted quiere {fruta_quiere} y cuestan {precio} €/Kg')
    continuar = input(f'Quiere continuar con la compra: ')
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes aclarar en tu pregunta que no funciona, y si recibis algun error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es simple, en un for-loop la variable que itera no se elimina despues de ejecutarse, por ejemplo:

```
frutas_precios = {'melones': 4, 'limones': 2}

for keys in frutas_precios:
    print(keys)

print("keys: ", keys)
```

Salida:

```
melones
limones
keys: limones
```

como vemos esa variable mantiene el último valor que tuvo como cualquier variable. Asi que el código `if fruta_quiere == (keys):` equivale a `if fruta_quiere == ('limones'):` y por ello obtienes que solo funciona para el último *key*.

Si quiere obtener los keys debes usar la función keys:

```
keys = list(frutas_precios.keys())
```

---

Si quieres verificar que un *key* esta dentro de un diccionario debes usar *in* como muestro a continuacion:

```
frutas_precios = {'melones': 4, 'limones': 2}

fruta_quiere = input('Que fruta le interesa (escriba ninguna para salir del modo de compra): ')

if fruta_quiere in frutas_precios:
    precio = frutas_precios[fruta_quiere]
    print(f'Usted quiere {fruta_quiere} y cuestan {precio} €/Kg')
    continuar = input(f'Quiere continuar con la compra: ')
```

Answer (score -2):

Para comprobar si una variable está como clave de un diccionario te recomiendo utilizar:

`if variable in diccionario:` es lo fallaba en tu código:

```
frutas_precios = {'melones': 4, 'limones': 2}

for keys in frutas_precios:
    print(keys)

fruta_quiere = input('Que fruta le interesa (escriba ninguna para salir del modo de compra): ')
if fruta_quiere in frutas_precios:
    precio = frutas_precios[fruta_quiere]
    print(f'Usted quiere {fruta_quiere} y cuestan {precio} €/Kg')
    continuar = input(f'Quiere continuar con la compra: ')
```

Comment: No di el downvote, probablemente te lo dieron porque no fundamentas el motivo del error y solo lanzas un código, te recomiendo leer [answer] y responder lo que el OP pregunta.

Comment: si eso fuese cierto, también deberían darlo a otros usuarios como: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190931/ejecutar-script-bash-desde-python-con-script-en-el-path

Comment: Yo estoy tratando de señalarte una posible causa para que mejores, si lo tomas a bien genial, si lo tomas a mal es tu problema, quizas sea el motivo el que te señale o quizas no pero desde mi humilde punto de vista cuando inicie a responder mis respuestas eran muy similares a las tuyas o peores, y en constraste la respuestas de otros usuarios que indicaban el error, señalaban buenas prácticas, etc. Por otro lado gracias por el downvote, esos son los mejores y los que me gustan :) Por favor lea el nuevo [Código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct)