# Ejecutar script bash, desde python, con script en el PATH

Tags: python, linux, bash, script, raspberry-pi

Tengo una carpeta con múltiples scripts que quiero llamar desde Python.

He añadido la carpeta al PATH para poder llamar estos desde cualquier directorio. Y se ha añadido correctamente:

```
user@myuser:~ export PATH=$PATH:~/misScripts

user@myuser:~ bash scriptEcho.sh

Hello world!
```

Pero cuando intento llamar a este desde Python me dice que el fichero no existe.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.5.3
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(['bash','scriptEcho.sh'])
bash: scriptEcho.sh: No such file or directory
CompletedProcess(args=['bash', 'scriptEcho.sh'], returncode=127)
```

Si a subprocess le añado shell=True, se cierra el intérprete y deja un proceso colgando (que no ejecuta el script de todas formas).

¿Alguna idea que por qué me dice que el fichero no existe, y cómo llamar a los scripts del PATH desde python?

Comment: Si usas export añades al PATH para esa sesión, si abres una nueva sesión en la terminal deberás volver a añadirlo, por eso Python no lo encuentra. En principio debes agregarlo a ~/.profile o ~/.bashrc o dependiendo del caso crer un link simbólico.

Comment: Perfecto @FJSevilla, es como decías, tengo que comprobar que al apagar y encender se mantiene, pero añadí el directorio en ~/.profile y ahora Python sí lo ve. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python tiene razón porque el script no está en el PATH cuando `subprocess` intenta acceder a él. Cuando haces  `$ export PATH=$PATH:~/misScripts` añades al `PATH` el directorio `misScripts` solo **temporalmente para esa sesión**, si abres una nueva terminal deberás volver a añadirlo, por eso Python no lo encuentra.

Si quieres agregarlo al PATH permanentemente debes editar el fichero `~/.profile` o `~/.bashrc` dependiendo de tu caso particular, añadiendo la línea:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/misScripts"
```

En ese caso  `subprocess.run(['bash','scriptEcho.sh'])` funcionará sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a poner `./` o `.\` delante del nombre del script.

```
>>> subprocess.run(['bash','./scriptEcho.sh'])
```